# How to create a App Specific User roles and access in Django?

Tags: django, model, roles, user-management

I want to create a user management system in Django where I will have multiple apps and for a single user, I want to assign different roles for the various apps as in the image below. Expert advice would be appreciated.
[The Image shows the different roles assigned to a user for different apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfRwl.png)

Comment: how are you managing user login? Are you using default username/password system provided by Django or have you implemented something specific?

Comment: I want to implement a custom user model and assign role for each app

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the user model as you want to use the custom user model. I would recommend that you inherit your user model with *AbstractUser* from django.contrib.auth.models.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # your custom fields here 

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

Add this User Model to your settings file

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'
```

After that, I would recommend to create a class *CustomLogin* and inherit it form *ModelBackend* from django.contrib.auth.backends.

If you want to use a custom scheme for login other than standard username/password, Override the **authenticate** function, otherwise leave it.

For permissions and roles part, I would recommend that you override the two function **_get_user_permissions** and **_get_group_permissions**. write your custom logic to provide permissions assigned a particular user and groups. you can use your roles as groups here and write custom logic.

Here is the documentation if you want to read further on this -
[Authentication Backend in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.backends)